# jQuery Timer: Start an event at x and end it at y

Tags: jquery, timer

I'm looking for a timer or a function in jQuery (or a plugin!) that would allow me to do the following: "At 25 seconds, show button x, at 45 seconds show button y, at 55 , stop showing x, at 65, stop showing y".

It seems pretty simple, but I keep coming up empty. I've found a lot of timers that will dispatch an event, but not end or hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
setTimeout(function() { /* code to show x */ }, 25000);
setTimeout(function() { /* code to show y */ }, 45000);
setTimeout(function() { /* code to hide x */ }, 55000);
setTimeout(function() { /* code to hide y */ }, 65000);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my first thought, I just wasn't sure if there was a more elegant way to go about it.

Comment: Good answer, but why the extra function? @Alnitak, beat me to it!

Comment: Good point. The extra function is unneeded. I haven't fully woken up yet. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind calculating the interval between events yourself:

```
$('#x').delay(25000).show().delay(30000).hide();
$('#y').delay(45000).show().delay(20000).hide();
```

alternatively, here's a plugin I just knocked up:

```
(function($) {
    var t0 = null;

    $.fn.timerAt = function(t) {
        var self = this;
        return this.queue(function(next) {
            var t1 = Date.now();
            var delay = Math.max(0, t0 + t - t1);
            setTimeout(next, delay);
        });
    };

    $.timerReset = function() {
        t0 = Date.now(); // use a shim on older browsers
    };

    $.timerReset();

})(jQuery);

$('#x').timerAt(25000).hide('slow').timerAt(55000).show('fast');
$('#y').timerAt(45000).hide('slow').timerAt(65000).show('fast');​
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the above solution, but this is awfully nice of you.

Comment: @GilloD strictly speaking you _should_ be using jQuery's animation queues to handle showing and hiding elements in sequence like this